# Incorrect range width error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

NOTE: This is a follow-up question derived from [Backup Google apps script not running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47954137/1595451)

The below code was running with some issues I have narrowed them down to only 1. I am getting the error

> Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 18 (line 41, file "update backup data")

This is the offending line

`archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, rng.getWidth()+1).setValues(data);`

The below link is for a copy of the sheet with dummy information on it.   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DR8XpNlRdZa17KqgnfBX3hxWKP5W4vrRJ_lj5uPNMlU/edit?usp=sharing

Below is the code

```
function dataBackup() 
{
var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1uPA_4CRmv2wkqe1uljViJ-1z1NTNDmwS3aE6TDowe88');
var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
for (var i=0; i<sheetNames.length; i++) 
{
var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
var date=inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue();     
var rng=inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37');
var dataA=rng.getValues();
var data=[];
for(var j=0;j<dataA.length;j++)
{
  if(dataA[j][0] && dataA[j][1])
  {
    data.push([dataA[j].splice(0,0,date)]);
  }
}
var dv=archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
date=(typeof(dv)!='undefined')?dv:'No Date Found';
if (data.length>0) 
{
  archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
  archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, rng.getWidth()+1).setValues(data);
} 
else 
{
  archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
}
}
}
```

The script is meant to copy information from selection e7-U37 and paste into an archive sheet and place the date taken from Cell A2 into the first column of archive sheet and if no information then "No Data" is entered.
Here is Archive test sheet.
        https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uPA_4CRmv2wkqe1uljViJ-1z1NTNDmwS3aE6TDowe88/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error. Checkout [Troubleshooting | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) to learn troubleshooting technics / tools. I suggest you to use Logger.log() in order to identify when the error occurs (the value of `i`, the sheet name, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

From your script, I think that because the length of each element of `data` which is 2 dimensional array is not the same to `rng.getWidth()+1`, the error occurs. So how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, rng.getWidth()+1).setValues(data);
```

#### To :

```
archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

### Note :

By the way, what will you do at below part?

```
var data = [];
for(var j=0;j<dataA.length;j++) {
  if(dataA[j][0] && dataA[j][1]) {
    data.push([dataA[j].splice(0,0,date)]);
  }
}
```

You use `data` at other parts, but here, it seems that the `data` becomes `[[[]], [[]], [[]], ...`. If this was the result you wanted, I think that this is no problem. Also I thought that this part may be related to the error.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.